# How to use Signalr in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, signalr

I have planned to use SignalR for my iOS application and searched for several hours to find a better solution but unfortunately I was not able to find a better solution for it.

Some of them where suggesting SignalR-ObjC for using SignalR in iOS but while I tried a sample with it, there were lot of issues on using [SignalR-ObjC](https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC).

I'm looking forward to hear some third party plugins which makes SignalR integration possible at iOS.

Kindly advice me on how to use signalr for iOS application.

Note: Just as an additional information I'm providing the errors that I have struggled with SignalR-ObjC. If the errors are fixable then I will go ahead using the SignalR-ObjC for now.

The issues are: None of my clients are not getting invoked by server method call but SRConnectionDidOpen was getting invoked everytime.

I have mentioned by code below, kindly review it and let me know if I had done anything wrong with my code as I'm a beginner to Objective C.

```
hub = [connection createHubProxy:@"myHub"];

[hub on:@"addMessage" perform:self selector:@selector(addMessage:)];

connection.started = ^{
NSLog(@"started");
};
connection.received = ^(NSString * data) {
    NSLog(@"%@",data);
};
[connection setDelegate:self];
[connection start];
}


- (void)addMessage:(NSString *)message{ // Print the message when it comes in
NSLog(@"message");
}
- (void)SRConnectionDidOpen:(SRConnection *)connection
{

[hub on:@"addMessage" perform:self selector:@selector(addMessage:)];


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you test your server-side code? Is it really working? Maybe it's not a client-side problem at all. If the server side is your job too, post the .net code here too! (Don't forget to update the question's tag list too)

Comment: Hey Rajesh, any update on this issue. Facing the same issue here. Connection is getting created, but nothing is getting invoked in the client side.(Using SignalR-ObjC)

Comment: @RintoRapheal : You can try this [link] (http://www.sathyabaman.com/2016/12/22/ios-implementing-signalr-using-objective-c/). By using this am able to send and receive msgs.

Comment: Thanks @Javeed. I have also implemented it and working fine so far.

Comment: Hi @Rajesh@Rinto, I also need to integrate SignalR in my App using Swift 3, Can anyone refer any link? Thanks in Advance.